# Event handling : Accessing another widget's property

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, event-handling

OK, this should be easy.

I tried to handle drop event onto a QGraphicsView widget. Incoming data dragged from a QTreeView widget. For that, I re-implemented these methods:

```
void QGraphicsScene::dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
    event.accept();
}

void QGraphicsScene::dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
    event.accept();
}

void QGraphicsScene::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
    event.accept();
}


void QGraphicsView::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    QPixmap pixmap(event->mimedata()->urls()[0].toString().remove(0,8));
    this.scene()->addPixmap(pixmap);
}
```

This works fine; but how can I change another graphicsview scene within this widget's drop event? That is:

```
void QGraphicsView::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    QPixmap pixmap(event->mimedata()->urls()[0].toString().remove(0,8));
    // I cannot access ui; and cannot access my widgets...:
    ui->anotherview->scene()->addPixmap(pixmap);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about making a custom signal in your QGraphicsView like `void showPixmap(QPixmap p)` and connecting it to a slot in your main gui class where you can access ui elements. You can then call `emit showPixamp(pixmap)` in the dropEvent.

Subclassing QGraphicsView

```
//header file
class CustomView : public QGraphicsView 
{
public:
    CustomView(QGraphicsScene*, QWidget*=NULL);
    ~CustomView();

signals:
    void showPixmap(QPixmap p);

protected:
    virtual void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);
};


//cpp file
CustomView::CustomView(QGraphicsScene *scene, QWidget* parent)
    :QGraphicsView(scene, parent) 
{
    //if you need to initialize variables, etc.
}
void CustomView::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    //handle the drop event
    QPixmap mPixmap;
    emit showPixmap(mPixmap);
}
```

Using event filters in your main GUI class

```
void GUI::GUI()
{     
    ui->mGraphicsView->installEventFilter(this);
}
bool GUI::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (object == ui->mGraphicsView && event->type() == QEvent::DropEnter) {
        QDropEvent *dropEvent = static_cast<QDropEvent*>(event);
        //handle the drop event
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: should I inherit graphics view class and create signals and objects from there? Or should I change qgraphicsview header?

Comment: You said you reimplemented those methods, how? You should not change QGraphicsView, you should subclass it.

Comment: I rewrote QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView's drag drop events (I actually got "inconsistent dll" warning but it worked fine) Is this a wrong way doing so? Should I promote my widgets into another class that inherits QGraphicsView; then place and reimplement drag events there?

Comment: yes you should definetely subclass it and then reimplement methods you need to use or you can use an event filter, check my edited answer

Comment: wow, I just learned about event filters. they are easier to handle, I really dont need subclassing. Thanks man